# How to recreate eBay New Logo Page in HTML + CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've had a great idea for a website, and I think the page that eBay has created for it's new logo is very interesting. I'm just wondering if anyone could give me any insight on how to recreate it.

http://pages.ebay.com/announcements/new/index.html

I sort of gather that the logo you can see through the gaps is set as the main bg, fixed and the front section just scrolls past it.

Two main questions:

- How do they get the 'front' div to fill the page
- How do they get the bg to change as you scroll down the page.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [viewing the source](http://pages.ebay.com/announcements/new/js/jquery.main.js)?

Comment: I've had a look at the CSS here: 
http://pages.ebay.com/announcements/new/css/all.css

I'm not too sure what I'm looking for though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. They have multiple background images that are applied to multiple `section` elements, then they have applied a `fixed` `background-attachment` so that the backgrounds are always in the same position. The result is an element which somewhat functions as a mask to its background.

You can really easily recreate the effect and so understand the implementation with this code:

*HTML*

```
<div></div>
<div class="ebay-img1"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="ebay-img2"></div>
<div></div>
<div class="ebay-img3"></div>
```

*CSS*

```
div { height: 600px; background-attachment:fixed; border-bottom: 1px solid black; }
.ebay-img1 { background: black url("http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/announcements/new/logo/logo-1.png") no-repeat 50% 0 fixed }
.ebay-img2 { background: black url("http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/announcements/new/logo/logo-2.png") no-repeat 50% 0 fixed }
.ebay-img3 { background: black url("http://pics.ebaystatic.com/aw/pics/announcements/new/logo/logo-3.png") no-repeat 50% 0 fixed }
```

​
See here for this code in situ: http://jsfiddle.net/CAMEn/

Answer (score 2):

The "background" is actually some `<section>` tags that are inserted between the actual content items. The illusion that it is the page background is achieved by specifying the `background-attachment: fixed;` style for the background elements.

Answer (score 0):

in the CSS source they're handing the changing background and div fills, it's not hidden so you can feel free to look at it and download and play with it :)